How can I make a flow so I can get notified when a new message is added in a channel
Hi I am trying to make flow which transfer any message posted in a channel irrespective whether it is a new root message or reply to existing message. In this the existing message part is tricky and i am stuck their.
I am open to any other process other than power automate i just want any and all messages from a teams channel to be sent to an email with the message details and heading of the post in the email.
I tried to see all the existing triggers in power automate but nothing only specifically gets triggered on a message in a channel without mentions to existing root post.


Create a flow in Power Automate that trigger when a new message is posted in a Teams channel. You can use the "When a new channel message is added" trigger to capture new messages.

Use 'Condition' to check if the message is a reply or a new root message. If the message is a reply, use the Microsoft Graph API to get the parent message and its replies. You can call the /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}/replies endpoint to get replies to a specific message. This will help you capture both new root messages and replies.

Once you have captured the message details, use the "Send an email" action in Power Automate to send the message details and heading to the desired email address.



Until now there is no such trigger in Power Automate which can watch replies, there is an idea in https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/idea/5a115ee1-bb91-470a-9481-d4865d91043f but is still not released by MS.
A workaround I know is to call MS Graph list replies API or list channel messages API with $expand=replies and loop through the responses and do your logic, but the disadvantage of this is those loops can consume more PPR (Power Platform Requests) and make you reach the limit if you don't restrict the frequency of the workflow runs. In your case if you just want to periodically send messages through emails it should be doable with the "Recurrence" trigger and the "Send a Microsoft Graph HTTP request" action.
